# Deducing class template parameters from variadic value-initialization (clang vs g++)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following *variadic class template*:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct foo
{
    template <typename... Us>
    foo(Us...) { }
};
```

If I try to instantiate `foo` in the following way, both **g++**(trunk) and **clang++**(trunk) are happy:

```
auto o = foo{};
```

[**on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/yJY8Y3)

---

As soon as I switch to *value-initialization* with parentheses, **g++** fails to compile (while **clang++** is still happy):

```
auto o = foo();
```

> ```
> error: cannot deduce template arguments for 'foo' from ()
>      auto o = foo();
>                   ^
> ```

[**on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/qbHTpo)

---

Is this a **g++** bug, or is there a difference in the way *class template argument deduction* is handled between `{}` and `()` initialization?

---

This also happens with a proper *deduction guide*:  https://godbolt.org/g/qReXpM.

Comment: I'd say both compilers are wrong - there is no way to deduce `Ts` using `Us`...

Comment: @W.F. also happens with a deduction guide. https://godbolt.org/g/qReXpM

Comment: @cpplearner this is definitely **not** a dup...

Comment: @VittorioRomeo when you provide the deduction guides - you provide the mapping between types of your constructor and the template parameters so there is no analogy there...

Comment: `g++` non-trunk says `error: missing template arguments before ‘{’ token` what is the difference between trunk and non-trunk?

Comment: cpplearner's dupe target is indeed a dupe if you include the deduction guides, but not if you don't, as that is another bug.

Comment: the difference in compilers behavior cannot be due to brace-initialization alone: if you replace the initialization with "auto o = new foo();" both compilers turn out happy ( note that due to  [expr.new]/2 the deduction of “new foo()” should be the same as in “foo o = foo();”)

Comment: @W.F. if a "trailing template parameter pack" at the end of argument dedeuction remains undeduced, it's fallback-deduced as empty. It's long been a mystery what "trailing" is supposed to mean in http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#3 . Compilers appear to not follow any "trailing" condition, for example in `template<typename ...T, typename U> void f(U); f(10); /* compilers make T empty */`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb totally forgot about this bullet... Need to reconsider my answer then ;)

Comment: @W.F. There might be a difference between `()` and `{}` w.r.t. overload resolution in class template argument deduction if the compilers consider the hypothetical class type to not have a default constructorl. Then `()` would not do overload-resolution, but just do zero-initialization. But `{}` will still do overload-resolution (not value initialization).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb this would surely explain why gcc and clang both accept the code... I'm still however not entirely convinced... Is the code really well-formed in this case?

Comment: EDIT: I must correct myself: As soon as there is no default constructor, we will also do overload resolution for `()` (to provoke an error, I guess). So it's still unclear to me. My best guess would then be that GCC just hasn't implemented http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1630 in all its glory yet.

Comment: Because it also happens with an explicit deduction guide, I would suspect there's somehting else going on, though.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What about [\[temp.res\]/8.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8.3). Wouldn't we face the situation where every valid specialization of the deduction guide template would require empty template parameter pack?

Comment: @W.F. i think that's http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2067 . The user-written constructor can be instantiated for non-empty `Ts...` (it is also not a template itself but a templated entity.. i.e member of a template).